# Test a Reactive Form field that has a custom validator in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, testing

I am trying to test the valid state of a custom validated field on a Reactive form.

My component is as below:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { ageRangeValidator } from './age-range-validator.directive';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Reactive Forms';
  genders = ['Female', 'Male'];

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

  userForm = this.fb.group({
    firstname: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2)]],
    surname: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2)]],
    address: this.fb.group({
      houseNo: [''],
      street: [''],
      city: [''],
      postcode: ['']
    }),
    // Section 1
    // age: [null, Validators.min(18)],
    // Section 2 - using a Custom validator
    age: [null, ageRangeValidator(18, 68)],
    gender: ['']
  });
}
```

The ageRangeValidator function is as follows - this has been fully tested and works:

```js
import { AbstractControl, ValidatorFn } from '@angular/forms';

export function ageRangeValidator(min: number, max: number): ValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: boolean } | null => {
    if ((!isNaN(control.value) && control.value) && control.value > min && control.value < max) {
      return { 'ageRange': true };
    }
    return null;
  };
}
```

I have a test for the App component set up as below where I set the value of the age field and then test to see if it is valid - the test returns validity to be false:

```js
import { TestBed, async, ComponentFixture } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { DebugElement } from '@angular/core';

describe('AppComponent', () => {
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;
  let app: AppComponent;


  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
      imports: [ReactiveFormsModule]
    }).compileComponents();

  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });
  
  describe(`Test the validity of the fields`, () => {
    it(`should return true if a value of 18 or more AND 68 or LESS is supplied (as string or number)`, () => {
      const age = app.userForm.controls['age'];
      age.setValue(42);
      expect(age.valid).toBeTruthy();
    });
  });
```

I expect that the solution will require the ageRangeValidator function to be hooked up to the test component in some way but I can't work out how - can anyone please suggest a way I could do this (if it is possible at all)?

Ultimately, I'm trying to test the validity of the form to ensure that it can be submitted when all required fields are valid.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use controls.get('age') try to avoid reaching controls directly
2. You need https://angular.io/api/core/testing/tick after setting the value to run validation process

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, I have implemented point 1!

Could you please expand on point 2 - I have tried converting the spec to a `fakeAsync` and introducing a `tick(1000)` but I get errors.  I'm not sure I follow exactly what you mean?

Comment: tick() (same as tick(0)) must be enough, because validation is waiting for the closest possibility to run a microtask.
Can you please show me the exact errors that it shows?

Comment: Again, thanks for the reply...my amended suite is now:

Comment: `describe('Test the validity of the fields', () => {
        it('should return true if a value of 18 or more AND 68 or LESS is supplied (as string or number)', fakeAsync(() => {
            const age = app.userForm.get('age');
            age.setValue(42);
            tick();
            age.updateValueAndValidity();
            tick();
            expect(age.valid).toBeTruthy();
        }));
    });`

Comment: Chrome 72.0.3626 (Mac OS X 10.14.3): Executed 1 of 1 (1 FAILED) (0 secs / 0.269 secs)
Chrome 72.0.3626 (Mac OS X 10.14.3) AppComponent Test the validity of the fields should return true if a value of 18 or more AND 68 or LESS is supplied (as string or number) FAILED
        Expected false to be truthy.
            at UserContext.<anonymous> src/app/app.component.spec.ts:79:31)
            at UserContext.<anonymous> node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js:1429:1)
            at

Comment: ZoneDelegate../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:391:1)
            at ProxyZoneSpec.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js.ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testingChrome 72.0.3626 (Mac OS X 10.14.3): Executed 1 of 1 (1 FAILED) ERROR (0.296 secs / 0.269 secs)

Comment: Hi Ed, sorry for the delayed answer. The problem is in your custom validator, so it must return null, when it is valid, and an object with errors in other case. Please check examples here https://angular.io/guide/form-validation .

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else that comes to this, if you have written your custom validator correctly you should not have to do anything special. If you are getting a reference error, just resave your files. There's nothing special you have to do to hookup the custom validator in the reactive form spec, you shouldn't even have to import it into the spec file.